# Wrong constructor in ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a constructor for my odom node but for some reason I keep getting the strange error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘rclcpp::TimeSource::TimeSource(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
 odom_pub{}, _odom_tb{std::make_shared<tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster>(shared_from_this())}
```

The thing is that I am not even trying to pass the rclcpp::TimeSource but my compiler thinks so. I think i managed to follow the variable declaration = variable initialization order, so for example in my header:

```
class OdomNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
    
private:
    int _rate, _ticks_meter, _left_pos, _right_pos, _enc_left, _enc_right, _lmult, _rmult;
    int _prev_rencoder, _prev_lencoder;
    double _d_left, _d_right;
    std::shared_ptr<tf2::Quaternion> q;
    std::string _base_frame_id, _odom_frame_id;

    //Node
    rclcpp::TimeSource _ts;
    rclcpp::Clock::SharedPtr _clock;
    std::shared_ptr<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped> _odom_ts;
    rclcpp::Rate _loop_rate;
    rclcpp::Time _then;

    // Subs and publishers:
    //rclcpp::Subscriber _left_sub;
    std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Publisher<nav_msgs::msg::Odometry>> _odom_pub;
    std::shared_ptr<tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster> _odom_tb;

    // Known vars:
    double _x{0};
    double _y{0};
    double _th{0};
    std::vector<double> _q_imu{0,0,0,1};
    std::shared_ptr<std_msgs::msg::Float64> _state_left, _state_right;
```

And my cpp file:

```
OdomNode::OdomNode() : Node("odometry_node","odometry_node_ns", rclcpp::NodeOptions()), _rate(30), _ticks_meter(1), _left_pos{0},
                       _right_pos{0}, _enc_left{0}, _enc_right{0}, _lmult{0},
                       _rmult{0}, _prev_rencoder{0}, _prev_lencoder{0},
                       _d_left{0}, _d_right{0}, q{std::make_shared<tf2::Quaternion>()},
                       _base_frame_id{"base_footprint"}, _odom_frame_id{"odom"},
                       _ts{this}, _clock{std::make_shared<rclcpp::Clock>(RCL_ROS_TIME)},
                       _odom_ts{std::make_shared<geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped>()}, _loop_rate{30},
                       _then{}, _odom_pub{}, _odom_tb{std::make_shared<tf2_ros::StaticTransformBroadcaster>(shared_from_this())}
{}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330243/wrong-constructor-in-ros2/) by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2019-08-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The time source

```
rclcpp::TimeSource _ts;
```

Is being initialized with `this`

```
_ts{this}
```

Which is of type `OdomNode *`, but [the only constructor that takes any arguments expects `rclcpp::Node::SharedPtr`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/41a99b64d347ce2ff8d5fd4ed8ebaa5cfbc5117f/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/time_source.hpp#L38).

However, `rclcpp::Node` already creates a time source and clock. Instead of creating a time source, [use `get_clock()` or `now()` since `OdomNode` inherits from `rclcpp::Node`](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/41a99b64d347ce2ff8d5fd4ed8ebaa5cfbc5117f/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node.hpp#L1064-L1070).

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-08-08**:
@sloretz Ok, I see now... Also, can you explain why am I getting this error:

```
[odometry_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
[odometry_node-1]   what():  bad_weak_ptr
```

I mean I know that this is because of hanged pointer but why does it happen? Is it because of

```
shared_from_this() ? I also have this line:
while(rclcpp::ok())
    {
        this->loop();
        this->_loop_rate.sleep();
        rclcpp::spin(shared_from_this());
    }
```

And I think it is the last line that brings me that error, as the shared_ptr was hanged. I tried to do this just before the while loop:

```
std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> _for_spin = std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>(this);
```

But it did not work

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2019-08-08**:
Please open a second question for the new error. Questions are easier to find than comments for future people with the same problem .

**Comment by [EdwardNur](https://answers.ros.org/users/39496/edwardnur/) on 2019-08-08**:
@sloretz Yes, I did :
https://answers.ros.org/question/330261/what-bad_weak_ptr/